# When iterating a map on Lightning, what is the closest approach to Visualforce's iteration?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, map

I mean, in Visualforce you can basically nest `apex:repeat` tags one inside another with maps. The first iteration on the keys, and then the second on the records.

This approach, however, does not seem to be possible on Lightning Components, because it is not possible to get the values from a map inside the expression on the `aura:iteration`. The following code doesn't compile:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!themap[akey]}" var="item">
...
</aura:iteration>
```

Is there a trick to iterate maps? What would be the recommended approach, since I need to display a list of lists on my component?

Comment: From what I've observed... no. But I hope I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your map into array of objects and then use that for iteration since aura:iteration can only work on lists.Since a Map gets converted to javascript object in client side we can convert that to Object array and use that for iteration.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array

Below is the link for array.map documentation from Mozilla site
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example

Hope this helps.